# Why is Pandas throwing error when using boolean indexer?

Tags: pandas

Why does the following not throw an error:

```
missing_val_count_by_column = (X_train.isnull().sum())
missing_val_count_by_column[missing_val_count_by_column > 0]
```

But this does:

```
combined_X = pd.concat([X_train, X_valid], axis=0)
null_columns = combined_X.isnull().sum()
dropped_columns = combined_X[null_columns > 0]

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean 
Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this :

```
dropped_columns = null_columns[null_columns > 0] # and not combined_X
```

In the former, the [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) succeeds because you're indexing a Series by a mask that has the same indices (*i.e the columns names*) while in the latter, you're indexing the concatenated DataFrame by a boolean mask (*a Series*) with different indices, hence the `IndexingError`.